# how to get CUDA syntax highlighting in Nsight VSCode extension when when cuda toolkit installed by Conda?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cuda, intellisense, nsight

I'm using Fedora 39 and installed cudatoolkit using `conda install` in a conda env (not base). When inside the conda env, I can do `nvcc foo.cu && ./a.out` and it works fine. (when I do `which nvcc`, it says `~/.conda/envs/foo-conda-env/bin/nvcc`).

However, when editing cu source files in VSCode using the C/C++ extension and NSight plugin the intellisense syntax highlighting appears to be ordinary C++, not Cuda: see screenshot.[image]

In particular, notice `__global__` is underlined. Of course there's also no autocomplete: when I type `cudaDevi`, it doesn't give me a menu with `cudaDeviceSynchronize` as one of the elements.

This is not surprising: I'm guessing if I had installed this to `/usr/bin` using nvidia's repo, so that the `bin` and libs and headers were all automatically in path, then the syntax highlighting would have worked fine. But if so, how do I tell the Nsight extension where to look for `nvcc` and the header files or whatever so that it can properly syntax highlight? I tried looking in user settings (UI) in VScode and there's absolutely nothing about NSight.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this to my satisfaction by going from the tab with my .cu file in VScode and doing "Select IntelliSense Configuration". Then giving it the path to my nvcc binary, which in my case was `/home/employee/.conda/envs/foo-conda-env/bin/nvcc`.

After that, both the syntax highlighting for `__global__` and the autocomplete were working perfectly.

[image]